# iOS TestFlight - how to provide 1024x1024 icon?

Tags: ios, app-store, testflight

Because the 1024x1024 icon size isn't actually needed by the app, I haven't included it in the build.  I uploaded the build and then uploaded the icon on the app store submission page in iTunes Connect, which seems to have worked for the app store submission.

However, I'm now trying to submit for public testing via TestFlight, but when I try to create a group, I get a message complaining that I haven't uploaded a 1024x1024 icon and that I can do so via iTunes Connect.  How do I do this?

Comment: Just add it to your asset catalog and you are done.

Comment: @Paulw11 (1) Does this mean the high res version is included in the downloaded app?  I'd like to avoid bloating it unnecessarily by including overly large graphics.  (2) Any suggestions how to do that for a Cordova app? I'm using the [cordova-icon](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-icon) script to generate the assets, but it doesn't seem to include the app store version.

Comment: If your large icon is more than a few hundred KB I would be surprised.  No idea on Cordova, sorry.

Comment: @Paulw11 - it's 250K, but that's a noticeable increase on a 4.5MB app.

Comment: I wouldn't worry about 250K, it is 5% of a 4.5MB app, but less than 2 seconds to download at a low speed like 1Mb/sec.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you submit an ipa generated through Xcode 9, iTunes Connect throws the below error:

```
Missing App Store Icon - iOS Apps must include a 1024x1024px App Store Icon in PNG 
format. Without providing the icon in the Asset Catalog or via iTunes Connect, apps 
cannot be submitted for App Review or Beta App Review. Refer to
https://developer.apple.com/ios/human-interface-guidelines/icons-and-images/app-icon/ for more information.
```

The same will be applicable only for the apps generated though Xcode 9+. If you want to avoid this, you still can generate the ipa using Xcode 8.

In Xcode 9, under App Icon section, there is a provision to add 1024*1024 icon.

- Go to Images folder in your project
- Navigate to Image.xcassets
- Click on AppIcon
- Navigate to bottom, there you will see App Store iOS 1024pt (1x)

[Screenshot of the app icon image asset with 1024*1024 icon available here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rx9Is.png)

Comment: "If you want to avoid this, you still can generate the ipa using Xcode 8." -- unfortunately, I'm using xcode 9 features (e.g. Swift 4) so cannot do this.

"In Xcode 9, under App Icon section, there is a provision to add 1024*1024 icon." -- I'm using cordova, which regenerates the xcode project files at every build, so I would need to do this every time I compile.  I've tried adding a 1024x1024 icon in my cordova config.xml file, but it doesn't seem to get used.  The error message says I can upload it via itunes connect instead, but I don't see how to do this.

Comment: Which cordova-ios version you are using? It was fixed in cordova-ios version: 4.5.1

Comment: I had 4.4.0.  That seems to have been the problem.